# Big O Notation - Is this O(n) or O(n2)?

Tags: javascript, big-o

I wrote a script that basically finds how many boxes can fit in another(bigger) box.

I have the `boxes` Array with all the box sizes and the `products` Array with the sizes of each product's box.

```js
let boxes = [
  {label:'box1', width: 4, height: 3, length: 12},
  {label:'box2', width: 6, height: 5, length: 14},
  {label:'box3', width: 8, height: 6, length: 24},
];

let products = [
    {name:'AudioBox3000 ',  width: 2, height:  1, length: 3},
    {name:'Canister1500 ', width: 5, height:  1, length: 11}
];

for(let j = 0; j < products.length; j++)  // O(n)
{
    createDiv('********' + products[j].name + '*********');
  
    for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)  // O(m)
    {
      let totalWidth  = Math.floor(boxes[i].width  / products[j].width);
      let totalHeight = Math.floor(boxes[i].height / products[j].height);
      let totalLenght = Math.floor(boxes[i].length / products[j].length);
      let totalBoxes  = totalWidth * totalHeight * totalLenght;
      createDiv(totalBoxes + ' boxes fits on ' + boxes[i].label); 
    }
}

function createDiv (value) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'app');
    div.innerHTML = value;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

So is clear that `for(let j = 0; j < products.length; j++)` is `O(n)`

and `for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++)` is also `O(n)`

So I'm confused if it is `O(n²)` or `O(n)`.

Could you elaborate an explanation?

Comment: n x n = n^2 ...

Comment: First there are *two* metrics: the length of the "products" list (call that *n*), and the length of the "boxes" list (call that *m*).  So because those inner computations happen *n* * *m* times, it's *O(n \* m)*

Comment: Hi German. Does my answer solve your question? If it does, could you please mark it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: done! thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's neither `O(n)` nor `O(n2)`.

Lets consider `N` as the number of products and `M` then number of boxes.

The time complexity of this algorithm is `O(N * M)`.

It's important to distinguish this 2 because for instance, let's imagine that the number of boxes is a fixed number, like 100... Then `M` would be a constant and therefore the time complexity of the algorithm would be linear. On the other hand, if the number of boxes can be expressed as a function of the number of products, like for instance, lets imagine that the number of boxes is the number of products power 2, in that case `M` would be equal to `N ^ 2`, so the time complexity would be `O(N^3)`.

If the number of products and the number of boxes are not related at all, and they both can grow differently, then the time complexity is definitely `O(N * M)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a loop inside another loop, then the total complexity will be O(n * n)

Comment: But what is *n*?  The number of products or the number of boxes?

Comment: Or, more generally, it's a number of operations

Comment: So if we write the same nested loop as a flat one it becomes O(n)?

Comment: If you can maintain the same algorithmic result, yes.

Comment: I'm not the OP.  @RobertHarvey right but there are *two lists* involved, so neither "*O(n)*" or "*O(n^2)*" really makes sense unless there's some constraint that the two lists sizes are always the same (or almost the same).

Comment: @Pointy `O(n * m)` then.

Comment: Saying that a loop inside another loop implies a quadratic time complexity is a pretty horrible over-simplification... I can think of many cases where that's not true. It could be `O(log(N) * N)`, it could be `O(N)`, it could be `O(N!)`, etc. It really depends on what and how it is being looped.

Comment: If our situation doesn't imply amortized cost, then this assumption should be correct. Did you mean such cases?

Comment: I'm saying that the statement "If you have a loop inside another loop, then the total complexity will be O(n * n)" is very unfortunate, because it is wrong. A loop inside a loop does not always imply a quadratic time complexity. In fact, in the case of the OP is asking for, is an example of a case where a loop inside a loop does not imply a quadratic time complexity.

Comment: totally agree with the statement of " A loop inside a loop does not always imply a quadratic time" and that is why my question ... @josep really clarify my question which was based on that scenario... having 2 arrays that won't relate each other.
... they both can grow in its own way or be as well static